# Testing for normality in compositional multivariate dataset in R

Tags: r, database, composition, normal-distribution, multivariate-testing

I am working with a compositional dataset with 30 variables. I am trying to analyse the data set using the package compositions. Before doing any stats though I would like to know the distribution of the multivariate dataset and whether it is normally distributed or not. Is it a problem if each nutrient ist differently distributed (some on their own normally and some not normally)?

So far however - using the tests of the compositions package acompNormalGOF.test(x) and mvnorm.etest I have not gotten any results. 
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Or can anyone suggest any other packages for working with multivariate data?

A sample of the data, it has been logx+1 transformed.

```
X1  Village Al  As  Ba  Ca  Co  Cr  Cu  Fe  Hg  K   Mg  Mn  Mo  Na  Nb  Ni  P   Pb  Rb  S   Sb  Se  Si  Sr  Ti  U   V   Y   Zn  Zr
1   2101    4.846009023 0.731703856 2.573976667 3.791336193 0.931167178 1.57084304  1.167359538 4.273445167 2.193054994 4.717629698 2.95887296  2.783713738 0.485112745 3.867976995 1.700110081 1.208402962 2.73644545  1.472045622 2.63159305  2.360858377 0.750948968 0.513788164 5.490611632 2.055170747 3.410754102 1.319462989 1.756059854 1.404736002 1.882573323 2.636387586
2   2104    3.771237308 0.553276046 2.638545163 3.378515817 0.773274348 1.41600774  0.991270389 3.754229883 0   4.432157058 3.592099444 2.322039335 0.550595207 3.825163124 1.474886135 0.918868743 0   1.203766975 2.060017543 1.135768515 0.75327657  0.416474079 5.759058294 1.87992123  3.19939284  0.713574538 1.599380833 1.178026788 1.460897843 2.847023892
3   2106    4.769558217 0.560803002 2.699332489 3.129173297 0.967021168 1.701546399 1.253459164 4.304780096 1.557507202 3.983753501 2.99870024  2.498567263 0.623507722 3.826944869 1.989822323 1.415182093 2.471183491 1.167206531 1.929916802 2.068209061 0.756541025 0.415599283 5.528741222 1.62104639  3.584578272 0.648238001 1.810811975 1.594406364 1.727724208 3.012666952
4   2107    4.646638806 0.595181173 2.697599195 3.673382339 0.931312549 1.930665276 1.220668348 4.221728843 2.345912588 4.470411814 3.458192644 2.682244384 0.497719275 3.84693079  1.517798928 1.457557514 2.524811392 1.237866754 2.135818436 2.36747839  0.770115295 0.416164829 5.579746802 2.012831201 3.393640374 0.671965834 1.744304162 1.234119396 1.703033305 2.646574553
```